# indir system-call

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

What is the system call `indir` ? Where can i find any information (signature, etc) about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This syscall?](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/2/indir)

Comment: Thanks, it is exatly what i need!